# Hoare Triple Derivation Example (Precondition False)

Tags: software-verification, hoare-logic

How can i derive this Hoare Tripel?

{false} x := x + 1; {x = 0}

I do not know which rule should i use on this.
I am confused on this wrong precondition.

Comment: Ex falso quodlibet.

Comment: $\text{false}\implies x+1=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hoare triple derivations use axioms and rules of Hoare logic. In this case, one would use (1) an instance of the assigment axiom followed by (2) an instance of the consequence rule. Yves Daoust's comment spells out the relevant premise (2).